# How To Insert Data With Matching Parameter Values From One Table to Another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables, the first one is the data table that I get daily from a source and the second one is a static table where there are parameter information for every 15 minutes.

The problem is, as you can see in the first table, I didn't get Value1 or Value2 for 00:15, 00:30 from the source. I want to insert the values with matching **all** parameters from table1 to table2. And if there is a mismatch, I want it to insert 0.

| Parameter1 | Parameter2 | Parameter3 | Parameter4 | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 1434 | A10 | B10 | 1 | 1 |
| 00:45 | 1434 | A10 | B10 | 2 | 2 |
| 01:00 | 1434 | A10 | B10 | 3 | 3 |
| 01:15 | 1434 | A10 | B10 | 4 | 4 |

| Parameter1 | Parameter2 | Parameter3 | Parameter4 | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 1434 | A10 | B10 |  |  |
| 00:15 | 1434 | A10 | B10 |  |  |
| 00:30 | 1434 | A10 | B10 |  |  |
| 00:45 | 1434 | A10 | B10 |  |  |
| 01:00 | 1434 | A10 | B10 |  |  |
| 01:15 | 1434 | A10 | B10 |  |  |
| 00:00 | 1434 | A11 | B11 |  |  |
| 00:15 | 1434 | A11 | B11 |  |  |

The final table should look like this.

| Parameter1 | Parameter2 | Parameter3 | Parameter4 | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 1434 | A10 | B10 | 1 | 1 |
| 00:15 | 1434 | A10 | B10 | 0 | 0 |
| 00:30 | 1434 | A10 | B10 | 0 | 0 |
| 00:45 | 1434 | A10 | B10 | 2 | 2 |
| 01:00 | 1434 | A10 | B10 | 3 | 3 |
| 01:15 | 1434 | A10 | B10 | 4 | 4 |
| 00:00 | 1434 | A11 | B11 | 0 | 0 |
| 00:15 | 1434 | A11 | B11 | 0 | 0 |

I tried to use =VLOOKUP function but I couldn't figure out how I was supposed to use it having multiple parameters and values.

The reason behind I'm trying to this on Excel is because I don't want to do all these process one by one on SQL. Here's how I do all these things on SQL one by one.

1. I import the raw data to SQL table.
2. I import the parameter values to another SQL table. (I import table2 so Value1 and Value2 come as NULL)
3. Then I update the parameter value table.
4. Now that I have the table I want, I simply change all the NULL values with 0. So that is an another step :)

Here is the update code for step 3:

UPDATE a
SET
a.Value1 = b.Value1,
a.Value2 = b.Value2,

FROM Table2 a

INNER JOIN
Table1 b
ON a.Parameter1 = b.Parameter1 AND a.Parameter2 = b.Parameter2 AND a.Parameter3 = b.Parameter3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `FILTER()` formula with. `BYROW()` for dynamically iterate each row and spill results.

```
=BYROW(H2:K7,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(E2:E5,A2:A5&B2:B5&C2:C5&D2:D5=CONCAT(x),0)))
=BYROW(H2:K7,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(F2:F5,A2:A5&B2:B5&C2:C5&D2:D5=CONCAT(x),0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you kindly check the question again after my edits :) I edited the tables for better understanding.

Comment: @Selim I have checked and same formula works for me. `=BYROW(H2:K9,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(E2:E5,A2:A5&B2:B5&C2:C5&D2:D5=CONCAT(x),0)))` Just you need to change `BYROW()` parameter from `H2:K7` to `H2:K9`